# How to edit or provide data values in Outlook Webaddin Manifest XML file in runtime

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Im working on developing an Outlook Webadin. In the manifest XML file of the addin I need to provide some of the elements values in run time. For example I need to read a port number from registry and then assign this port number to SourceLocation in

< SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:5005/" />

Is there a way to do it via code? or any other way in which I can provide these values in run time.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no to set values in manifest xml (port number) dynamically. Infact, it is not recommended way to set port number based on registry settings. Since outlook-web-addins are support to work on all platforms: Outlook Windows, Outlook Mac, Outlook Web (OWA): How would it work on other platforms if we set port number from Outlook Windows only? Ideally, outlook web addin should be hosted somewhere and appropriate port number should be assigned and used in manifest statically.

Comment: In our case, our application is supported only on Windows platform. Actually the Outlook Web addin is an extension of one of our Windows based application. So we are not concerned about running on other platforms than Windows.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix the port number.  What are you using as a web server?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to change port number they way you described it (dynamically). You will have to mention port number in manifest statically.

Comment: Brian Clink, out web server will run on localhost only. It is designed for running on the user machine only. We are hosting in Windows Service with Kestrel. We are not using IIS.

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, ok. I fwe change the port number, we require to remove the current addin and add the addin again with manifest file. That is ok for us. I am only wondering if i can change the port number with C#  XML code.

Comment: if the requirement is to interact with registry, you could use VSTO add-in and load url based on settings. Web add-in manifest can not be changed on runtime.

Comment: curious, other than source location, what are the other settings you would want to change on runtime?

Comment: Pallav, No other settings. Actually the source location change issue has come up because of probable change in the port number on which the service can be opened. Because the service is running on the single machine meant to be consumed by the logged in user, before opening the port we are required to check that if the port is available. If the port is not available then it could be opened on any other available port. And hence comes the issue of changing the port in Manifest file.

Comment: Currently the feature:dynamically update port number in manifest, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT , okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the feature:dynamically update port number in manifest, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page (officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/…). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.